# How to download ".apk" as ".apk"? (not as ".zip")

Tags: android

I have a small problem. Some browsers are not downloading the ".apk" files correctly.
How to download ".apk" as ".apk"? (not as ".zip")
Some browsers are convert them to ".zip".

I mean, the ".apk" file on my server and some people calling me and asking, how to rename ".zip" to ".apk".

Comment: The browser is "Internet Explorer 7" on "Windows XP SP2".

Comment: What is being set as `Content-Type` in the response headers? You may need to add a mime type mapping.

Comment: I just need a code... which will help to download ".apk" as ".apk"

Comment: It depends on your web server. You don't need "code" unless you're manually serving the files, which you have not indicated you are. If you *are* setting the files, you can manually set the response content type.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Create a MIME-TYPE mapping of `apk` to `application/vnd.android.package-archive`. How you do this will vary on your web server.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171418/download-apk-with-downloadmanager

Answer (score 8):

For IIS7 and higher, add the following to the `web.config` of your application:

```
<system.webServer>
   <staticContent>
     <mimeMap fileExtension="apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
   </staticContent>
<system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also set in web.config for local server for downloading apk

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Commit an answer for **Nginx**:

Add this line in *mime.types*,

`application/vnd.android.package-archive     apk;`

If this won't work, try to return an explicit header for `*.apk` in your site conf,

```
location ~* \.(apk)$ {
    add_header Content-Type application/vnd.android.package-archive;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I will say better to set this:

`location ~ \.apk$ {
  add_header Content-Type application/vnd.android.package-archive;
}`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me -

It's a known issue but easy to fix.

1. Login to the Web server using SSH
2. Verify that the apk mime doesn't exist in nginx mime.types by running:

> cat /etc/nginx/mime.types

3. Add apk mime type application/vnd.android.package-archive     apk;  into mime.types file using nano tool or vi (make sure it is inside the 'types{}')

> nano /etc/nginx/mime.types

4. Restart nginx service

> /etc/init.d/nginx restart

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you serve the files nor what server you're using.

It might have something to do with serving the files with the correct MIME type.

The following is for Apache, but I'm sure IIS also would support adding MIME types.

[Can't install APK hosted my own apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569313/cant-install-apk-hosted-my-own-apache-server#answer-4552662)

Comment: New browsers are downloading ".apk" correctly. Only old browsers - not!

Comment: @user922907: That's why you need to force the MIME type.

Comment: When I will have an access to the server, I will write the result.

Answer (score 0):

Please Change the MIME-TYPE mapping of apk to application/vnd.android.package-archive

How to add a MIME type to a Web site or application
1.  Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager: 
o   If you are using Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2: 
§   On the taskbar, click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager. 
o   If you are using Windows Vista or Windows 7: 
§   On the taskbar, click Start, and then click Control Panel. 
§   Double-click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager. 
2.  In the Connections pane, go to the site, application, or directory for which you want to add a MIME type.
3.  In the Home pane, double-click MIME Types.

1. In the MIME Types pane, click Add... in the Actions pane.
2. In the Add MIME Type dialog box, add the file name extension as .apk and MIME type as application/vnd.android.package-archive, and then click OK.

Answer (score 0):

If You are running an **Apache2 server**:

1. Go to **/etc/apache2/mods-available**
2. Find file named: **mime.conf**
3. Add this string `AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk`
4. **Save** the file
5. Go to **/etc/apache2/mods-enabled**
6. Find file named: **mime.conf**
7. Add this string `AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk`
8. **Save** the file
9. **Restart** Your server.