# Download .apk with DownloadManager

Tags: android, file, ftp, apk, download-manager

Hi I'm facing a little problem here. For updates of my App (that isn't available in Play Store) I download it via `DownloadManager` to the Donwload directoryof the device. The .apk file is on a ftp server.

After downloading I pop up a dialog if the user wants to install the update (not malicious or something, no root needed). Everything works fine **except** the user cancels this dialog and wants to "manually" install the apk by clicking on the downloaded file in the Download diretory. If so, I **don't get the Package-Installer** to choose to open the file. On some devices "HTML Viewer" is opened without a question. If I download the apk via QR-Code (direct link) from browser everything is fine, so I guess it's a failure coming with the DownloadManager.

**How can I download a file from ftp *with DownloadManager*, so that it is recognized as .apk and I can install it from the download region?**

Here's the code for downloading and installIntent:

```
String url = "http://www.test.xx/myApp.apk";
Uri mUri = Uri.parse(url);
DownloadManager.Request r = new DownloadManager.Request(mUri);
r.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "myApp.apk");
r.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
dm.enqueue(r);
```

And on download receive:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        long myDownloadID = DashboardActivity.this.mSharedPref.getLong(PreferenceIdentifier.DOWNLOAD_APK.toString(), 0);
        mSharedPref.edit().remove(PreferenceIdentifier.DOWNLOAD_APK.toString()).commit();
        long downloadCompletedId = extras.getLong(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID);
        DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();

        if (myDownloadID == downloadCompletedId) {
            q.setFilterById(downloadCompletedId);
            DownloadManager mManager = (DownloadManager) MyActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Cursor c = mManager.query(q);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                    if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                        Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        promptInstall.setDataAndType(
                            Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/myApp.apk")),
                                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                            promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(promptInstall);
                    }
            }
            c.close();
        }
```

As you can see I did

```
promptInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/myApp.apk")),
"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

I thought that would set the file type to apk so it is handles as one.

Hope I made my point clear, can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, well... kinda stupid..

```
promptInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/myApp.apk")),
"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

just affects the way android want to open the file..

```
DownloadManager.Request r = new DownloadManager.Request(mUri);
            r.setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

will do it...