# APK file storing as archive type in downloads folder of device

Tags: android, installation

Issue: I downloaded APK file from browser using url and when I try to install this apk from device's downloads folder it opens apk as archive folder. While I am able to install apk from any third party file manager / explorer.

Can anyone suggest me what settings or issue is there?

Comment: try like this long click --> open with --> package installer

Comment: @Redman I want to install directly by single click as usually we do

Answer (score 0):

check the open by default set by package installer and inbuilt file manager.
clear them if set.

Answer (score 0):

After a big R & D I found solution I referred below link

[How to download ".apk" as ".apk"? (not as ".zip")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296829/how-to-download-apk-as-apk-not-as-zip)

I just added MIME type in web.xml at server end

application/vnd.android.package-archive