# android .apk is getting downloaded as a .zip file on mobile chrome browser

Tags: android, appsflyer

When i try to download a .apk android file using an appsflyer universal link it is getting downloaded as a .zip file on Chrome but works fine on firefox.

Comment: Talk to appsflyer's customer service, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Create a MIME-TYPE mapping of `apk` to `application/vnd.android.package-archive`. How you do this will vary on your web server.

Comment: where we need to create MIME-TYPE mapping of apk

Comment: above answer was copy pasta'd from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296829/how-to-download-apk-as-apk-not-as-zip