# Set headers for .apk files served by nginx

Tags: nginx, header

In my server block I have

```
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://echocdn;
      include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
      add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, private, no-transform, no-cache";
      location ~* \.apk$ {
         add_header Content-Type application/vnd.android.package-archive;
         add_header Content-Disposition "attachment";
      }
   }
```

If I remove the inner location block, I can reach the APK file (and all other files).

With the block added, any .apk file returns a 404.  How do I add the headers for APK files?

Note: Content types for other file types are handled well by the included mime.types, but even if I add the line for APK files as described [How to download ".apk" as ".apk"? (not as ".zip")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296829/how-to-download-apk-as-apk-not-as-zip) and https://blog.mypapit.net/2015/08/how-to-set-apk-mime-type-for-nginx-web-server.html it only returns a content-type of text/html for apk files.

Comment: You need to have proxy_pass inside the apk block also.

Answer (score 2):

maybe it's better not to set a header directly, for me it resulted in a double content-type.

but if you declare it in the location-block types it also works fine.

take a look:

```
  location ~* \.apk$ {
    types {
      application/vnd.android.package-archive apk;
    }

    add_header Content-Disposition "attachment";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have proxy_pass inside the apk block also. Nginx doesn't work like a programming language so you are not executing anything from the parent block.

Also for setting the content type using `default_type` directive

```
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://echocdn;
      include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
      #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
      add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, private, no-transform, no-cache";
      location ~* \.apk$ {
         default_type application/vnd.android.package-archive;
         add_header Content-Type application/vnd.android.package-archive;
         add_header Content-Disposition "attachment";
         proxy_pass http://echocdn;
      }
   }
```

You can even handle this with a if

```
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://echocdn;
      include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
      #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
      add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, private, no-transform, no-cache";
      if ($request_uri ~* \.apk$) {
         default_type application/vnd.android.package-archive;
         add_header Content-Type application/vnd.android.package-archive;
         add_header Content-Disposition "attachment";
      }
   }
```

Comment: Adding the proxy_pass directive inside the inner block gets rid of the 404 - the file is now found, but the Content-Type is still text/html.

Comment: The if-directive option would not start until I removed the default_type directive (The log said it cannot be used there).  Without it, it acts the same as the other option - the file is received but the content-type is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location ~*.(apk)${
    root /tmp/app; 
    add_header Content-Disposition attachment;
}
```

/tmp/app is your APK files full path.