# Create download link for my apk file

Tags: php, android, http, ftp

i`m trying to crate direct download link for my app on sever, meanwhile with no success. 
The apk location is 
http://breeze-animation.com/shamir/apks/liverpool.apk
on my server, but the browser not download the file, and i get "Not found" notice in the browser. How can i crate download link for apk? it works fine with zip and pdf files, for example:
http://breeze-animation.com/shamir/apks/1.zip

Comment: Perhaps you need to add the apk extension to Apache, so it knows how to handle the file type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569313/cant-install-apk-hosted-my-own-apache-server

Answer (score 2):

Check the mime-type configuration on your server.

[APK files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29)

Comment: you just need to include that final ')' in the hyperlink. It gets you there as it is, but you have to go through the 'Did you mean' redirect to find 'The MIME type associated with APK files is application/vnd.android.package-archive'