# My Android smartphone can't download apk from my Apache server, is it a Mime-type issue?

Tags: android, apache, tomcat, mime-types, apk

I have `MyApplication.apk` in a directory named `downloads` on my Tomcat Apache server, and I made a link to that file in a web page so my Android Smartphone would be able to download and install it. However, it can't download it, whereas my PC web browser can.

I did some research on Stackoverflow ([this subject for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569313/cant-install-apk-hosted-my-own-apache-server)) and the web, and found out that I had to add the mime-type for apk files in my server (in the file web.xml in the project named `Server` in Eclipse). I did that.

I also saw that I had to create an `.htaccess`, place it in the contexts I called, and write a line to add apk mime-type. I also did that.

But I still can't download my apk in my smartphone web browser ! Does anyone has an idea ?

NB : I use Eclipse to run my Apache Tomcat. My application is signed and its weight is 1.5MB.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't dowload it" ? What happens ?

Comment: the download lasts forever until I stop it. I want to add I have a valid Internet connection (3G+) which works very well with others downloads (e.g. APKs from other sources, other files...).

Comment: How do you know it lasts forever ? Doesn't it show up in the list of downloads in the browser ?

Comment: Yes it shows up but there is not title for the downloaded file, and the progress bar is undeterminated.

Comment: And I assume touching it won't launch the install process ?

Comment: You're right, because the download is not complete.

Comment: Humm.. that's strange, I serve APKs through apache 2 all the time without even adding the mime type. Is your internal flash disk full ?

Comment: No it is not. I have to run Apache on Windows (a wish of the company I work for), so I didn't find /etc/conf and others useful folders for configurating Apache

Answer (score 0):

Should put `mime-type:application/vnd.android.package-archive`